# How Erlang atoms can be garbage collected

Tags: garbage-collection, erlang

It is said that atoms are not garbage collected. Once you’ve created an atom, it remains in the atom table, which might cause memory leakage at the end of the day!

I'm fairly new to Erlang, and my question is: How the atoms can be garbage collected? And if not possible, how to minimize that effect?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Atoms aren't issue unless you are creating them dynamically. If you did that, then you are on your way to crash an Erlang system.

How to create Atoms dynamically? 
For example calling **list_to_atom** function inside a loop.

If you are interested in Erlang garbage collection, then read this paper by Joe Armstrong: [One Pass Real-Time Generational Mark-Sweep Garbage Collection (1995)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary;jsessionid=0397570F246B379399EB5A3FDDFF2C5E?doi=10.1.1.42.7791).

Always keep in mind: ***Don't create Atoms dynamically!***
Well sometimes you might need to create an Atom dynamically BUT don't over use it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is: If it happened and I used them dynamically, how can I free memory of them?

Comment: You have very few risk of memory leakage, because the number of different atom is limited. So you will hit this issue before you have memory consumption problem (by default the max number of atom is `1 048 576`)

Comment: Well I am no more confident in the behavior of the VM, I tried this: `[list_to_atom(integer_to_list(X)) || X <- lists:seq(1,1048577)].` in the shell, and it hangs infinitively, while the same loop with 1 000 000 atoms works fine.

Comment: To clarify, *"Don't overuse it"* means that you should only use it when you know there is an upper bound on how many atoms you will create. For example, creating atoms for element names in a valid HTML document is upper-bounded by the number of defined element types in the HTML standard.

Answer (score 5):

While I'm not sure atoms are garbage-collected, you can easily do without worrying whether you will blow up the system's memory. As @Chiron said, as long as all your atoms are known at compile time you should be ok.

What if I really need to use `list_to_atom/1` somehow? Well, you may be able to twist your issue using this kind of function:

```
atom("apple") -> apple;
atom("orange") -> orange;
atom("banana") -> banana.
```

One other workaround is [`list_to_existing_atom/1`](http://erldocs.com/R16B02/erts/erlang.html?i=0&search=list_to_existing#list_to_existing_atom/1)

But the VM can still eat more and more RAM: other connected Erlang nodes may register atoms globally, that is allocate atoms at run time.

Answer (score 1):

From [learn you some Erlang](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#atoms):

> Atoms are really nice and a great way to send messages or represent
>   constants. However there are pitfalls to using atoms for too many
>   things: an atom is referred to in an "atom table" which consumes
>   memory (4 bytes/atom in a 32-bit system, 8 bytes/atom in a 64-bit
>   system). The atom table is not garbage collected, and so atoms will
>   accumulate until the system tips over, either from memory usage or
>   because 1048577 atoms were declared.
>
> This means atoms should not be generated dynamically for whatever
>   reason; if your system has to be reliable and user input lets someone
>   crash it at will by telling it to create atoms, you're in serious
>   trouble. Atoms should be seen as tools for the developer because
>   honestly, it's what they are.